"Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'" Next.js Build Fails on Vercel with Autoprefixer Error Despite Local Success
encountering some weirdness in deployment on Vercel. It puzzled me.
Deployment log reports the following errors:
1：Version inconsistency:
Package.json specifies Next.js 15.0.0
Vercel detects 14.2.14
Build runs with 15.0.0
This might explain the missing interception-routes module
2：Module resolution looking in wrong places:
Missing internal Next.js module (interception-routes)
Autoprefixer being sought in yarn's global modules instead of project's node_modules
# Version Mismatch:
[22:55:03.055] Detected Next.js version: 14.2.14
[22:55:06.976]   ▲ Next.js 15.0.0

# Module Resolution Error:
Failed to compile.
./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/utils/is-dynamic.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../../../../server/future/helpers/interception-routes'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/utils/index.js
./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/page-path/denormalize-page-path.js
./node_modules/next/dist/server/get-page-files.js
./node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js

# Autoprefixer Error:
Error: Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/config/blocks/css/plugins.js


Keep in mind this is not happening in my local environment, only when deploying on Vercel.
#local
> next build
▲ Next.js 15.0.0
Creating an optimized production build ...
✓ Compiled successfully

below are my relevant package.json. I followed the instructions of claude and it told me to move the packages from devDependencies to dependencies, because Vercel tends to strips out devDependencies after installing them to minimize the production bundle size. I have no clue so I just followed.
"dependencies": {
  "autoprefixer": "^10.4.20",
  "tailwindcss": "^3.4.14",
   "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7"
  "next": "14.1.4",
  "@prisma/client": "^5.16.1",
  ...
},
  "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "20.11.24",
        "@types/react": "18.2.61",
        "@types/react-dom": "18.2.19",
        "eslint": "^8",
        "eslint-config-next": "15.0.0",
        "typescript": "5.3.3"
    },
  ...
}

I've tried several solutions according to claude and cursor and none of them work. I've tried reinstalling dependencies and clearing the cache, but the issue persists. I tried overiding the build command in Vercel's project setting using npm install autoprefixer postcss tailwindcss && npm install && next build. Also tried to force installation on the autoprefixer, changed dependencies configurations, but the error just won't go away. Neither does the Module not found: Can't resolve '../../../../server/future/helpers/interception-routes' error.
BTW, Claude suggests that there might be a build Environment Inconsistency, that Vercel is using global yarn modules: /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/ while I only use npm's  local node_modules/. I am fairly new so I have no clue how this might/might not causes any of my observed trouble.
I'm expecting on Vercel it deploys just as good as it does locally when I run npm run build. I expected the Vercel build process to correctly recognize and use both the next.js version and autoprefixer during the production build, without any issues related to version mismatch or missing modules. I anticipated that after clearing the cache and reinstalling dependencies, the build would proceed without errors, especially since it works fine locally.
Thank You

Never mind, I copied and pasted my whole src folder to another new directory and constructed a new project root directory and it worked. Total reconstruction worked.
